# Replace the point on coma between two digits

Tags: preg-replace

Can you please tell me how to correctly make a regular expression to replace a point with a comm between two digits in a sentence.
For example:

```
Text text 119.20 text. Text text.
to
Text text 119,20 text. Text text.
```

I found such an example, but this expression incorrectly handles 4-digit numbers.

```
preg_replace('/([\d]).([\d])/','$1,$2',$example);
```

Comment: it only mishandles 4 digit numers if they are formatted like this:  1,123,133.02 - which is (I think) the us way of using thousands-seperators. Its difficult to get a regex for that - your program is unable to decide if 1,234 is 1234.00  or 1+234/1000 - no regex can distinguish those 2. German would format above number like this: 1.123.133,02. In any case, please provide replacementdata for :  `1,123,456.00`  `1,234`, `53,123,123` , `1.123,44`  - what should each one be replaced with?

Comment: In all cases, I just need to replace the point with a coma in those cases, if before and after the point exist a digit in sentence.

Comment: You must escape the dot, use `'/(\d)\.(\d)/'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex will cut the number when it founds it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've modified your regex to do as you wish:

```
$test_string='Text text 119.20 text. Text text.';

$regex_numbers=preg_replace('/(\d)\.(\d)/', '\1,\2', $test_string);

echo $regex_numbers;
```